# How to Route a Button command from a View to numerous ViewModels

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I am using the MVVM pattern in my WPF application. In one of my Views I have a button that when clicked uses Commands to talk to its ViewModel. The problem I have is that I need the ViewModel to then talk to other ViewModels to call some of their public methods. I use IOC (Unity) and inject the container into the first ViewModel, so could access the others by using this. I’m not sure if this fits in with the MVVM concept.

Is it possible for all my ViewModels to somehow subscribe to the one button click? 
Are any of these the recommended way of solving this problem or is there a better way?

To explain a bit more about my application, each view is a tab control with several textboxes. On the first tab there is also a button and combobox. The user is free to enter their own data or select an option from the combo. In this instance, if the button is then clicked I need all the tabs to load their textboxes based on the selected item in the combo from the first tab. I somehow need to wire this button click in such a way that the value from the combo is passed to all the related viewmodels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)**. Have the command publish an event that the other ViewModels can subscribe to. 
When the event is raised they'll all get the event, without needing for one VM to know the other VMs

Another option is to use **[Composite Commands](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Working-with-Prism-4-Part-3-Composite-Command-and-Pub-Sub-Events.aspx)** instead of a regular command.
Make the command the button uses a composite command, and have the other viewmodels [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec3) to that Composite command.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've gone down the EventAggregator route, with a bit of help from this site: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/

Answer (score 0):

You could go a few ways with this one:

- use some kind of eventing framework to notify all subscribers if something happens: eg [Prism EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx). For this to work you'll need to set up Prism obviously. There are other (MVVM) frameworks out there which support some kind of event/message system like [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) or [MVVMLight](http://www.google.com/search?q=mvvmlight)
- Create a `MasterViewModel` that contains all the child viewmodels for all the tabs. This way the 'master' can subscribe to the PropertyChanged events from its children and execute the appropriate actions. Or the Master can even contain the commands which you are binding to.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some form of "Messenger" service.  By this, I mean a class that implements the "Subscription Pattern."

I'm not sure which MVVM library you might be using, but if you look at the "MVVM Light Toolkit" - which is available on CodePlex - you will find a very light implementation of a Messenger there.

Basically each ViewModel will subscribe to receive a specific notification and your ViewModel with the combo box and button will publish the message when the button is clicked.  It is really quite flexible in how you send the messages and your ViewModels don't need to know anything about each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MVVM lite toolkit from GalaSoft you have access to the Messenger which would allow you to send a message that you can subscribe to in each of your view models.

```
// Send message from command handler
Messenger.Default.Send<MyMessage>(new MyMessage());

// Register for message in view models.
Messenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, MyMessageReceived);

// Method to do work
private void MyMessageReceived(MyMessage myMessage)
{
// Do Work
}
```